# Redis timeouts occurring with load test (No connection is available)

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, redis, timeout

I could really do with some help diagnosing a problem with Redis. We're currently load testing our web application and at to around 500 RPM then we hit the error below. We're using Azure Infra and tried app service and VM's with the same result on both.(single instances D2v2)

The MVC application uses a lot of Async await threads and it does bounce off 100% CPU but the App never crashes. I've looked at how the multiplexer was implemented and it would appear that the DI set up Redis as a singleton. I believe this is correct but would like some input if this isn't correct?

- [Redis IOC example using Simple Injector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJEFf.png)
- [Redis DB provider example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQXiF.png)
- [Redis example cache provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ml6J.png)
- [Example of calling the cache from Async method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0acL.png)

The above hopefully shows the configuration from DI all the way to the Redis call, and I would like to know if there are any basic bad practices with mixing Async vs Syncronous calls for example which might be attributing to the Redis problem we're seeing under load. I've read some articles where Redis might max out connections or threads on the consuming app, but we're struggling how to determine, trace this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as our dev team are struggling to come up with a solution or explanation i'm happy with. Also, if there isn't enough information to feedback on here, please let me know and i will add stuff to help.

Redis version 2.0.600

```
No connection is available to service this operation: GET WestEurope_Garage_4_GarageModel; SocketClosed on XXXXX.net:6380/Interactive, Idle/MarkProcessed
```

[Full Redis error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XM1f.png)